# Does the word "midnight" mean only 12 o'clock at night?

Tags: time

Does the word "midnight" mean only 12 o'clock at night?

Is 1:30 AM midnight? Could you teach me?

Answer (score 6):

*Midnight* has two basic meanings:

1. More precisely: twelve o’clock at night.
2. More loosely: the middle parts of the night.

However, only the first of these two meanings is common.

As a standalone noun (“It is midnight”), the meaning is **always** twelve o’clock at night exactly (or more or less exactly, as always with time notations).

When used as an *adjunct* (= a noun used as though it were an attributive adjective), the meaning depends on what it is modifying. If the noun modified refers to a longer period of time, such as *hours* in the set phrase *midnight hours*, then the meaning is a bit looser. This makes some sense, since having a period of several hours being modified by a specific point it time makes little sense—you wouldn’t say a “two o’clock afternoon” either.

With the word *hour* (in the singular), there is a specific meaning: the *midnight hour* is the hour that **starts** at midnight and goes on till one o’clock in the morning.

When *midnight* is used to modify other nouns, it usually retains its more specific meaning: a *midnight train* is one that leaves around twelve o’clock at night, for example, not just one that leaves some time during the late hours of the night or the early hours of the morning.

So no, 1:30 AM is not midnight, but it is *in the middle of the night*, which is the most common phrase used to describe the night as a whole, but without counting its very beginning and end. 4:30 AM would still be nighttime, but it would probably not be considered to be in the middle of the night (except by people who are very late risers).

Comment: Thank you for the answer in detail. Your explanation is very helpful.

Comment: A*midnight snack* isn't necessarily eaten at precisely midnight, and honestly I wouldn't be surprised by a midnight train leaving any time between 10 pm and 4 am.